# Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSObject100'

Tags: sql-server, ssis

whenever i opend my ssis package giving error message

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSObject100'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{30E5D0EF-E33D-4945-8A7F-F5178FC64C24}' failed due to the following error: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)). (Microsoft Visual Studio)

[image]

found one solution from google

Open the command prompt

Navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn

Run C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn>regsvr32 dts.dll

i already try this solution but not work for me got error message like not compatible for 32 or 64 bit version 
do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Do you have a script task? Whenever i have this error, its because it has been opened corrupted. But mine however always dissapears again

Comment: @plaidDK nope i donot have script task

Comment: Try to rebuild the part of the task that is failing into a new solution. Just to make sure something isn't corrupt in your project.

Comment: @tonyd basically,all the ssis package completely work on production environment and i just extract ssis package from production environment to my local machine and then got error that means issue not on SSIS package but i donot know what is the main issue

Comment: In that case, are there any 3rd party extensions installed on your production server that you don't have on your computer? 3rd party extensions need to be installed in both environments. These would be like extra tasks that don't come included with SSIS. For example, an SFTP task.

Comment: I have same problem, have you a found a solution alredy?

Comment: I tried the regsvr32 dts.dll solution, with admin at cmd and did not work...

Answer (score 0):

Found a Workaround:
Just Generate a New ID for the package and Rebuild!